# Jasmine-reporters not generating any result file

Tags: protractor, jasmine-reporters

I have following versions in my system

```
jasmine - reporters@1.0.0
node - v4.5.0
protractor - 4.0.10
```

and I am not able to generate any result file. for my scripts Is it some compatibility issues with these versions,
I have also tried with jasmine-reporters - 2.0.0
still no luck.

Please help me thanks

my conf.js looks like

```
capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox
    },

    onPrepare: function() {

       //The require statement must be down here, since jasmine-reporters
       //needs jasmine to be in the global and protractor does not guarantee
       // this until inside the onPrepare function.
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        require('jasmine-reporters');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('testresults', true, true));
    },

    specs: [
            'Apps/ImportApp/importEMC.js',
    ],
```

I have also tried with jasmine-reporters 2.0.0 and code was

```
framework: 'jasmine2',
onPrepare: function() {
var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    consolidateAll: true,
    savePath: 'testresults',
    filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
}));
},
```

for this it gave me error as

> jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter is not a function

Error Log

> at exports.config.onPrepare (D:\HalomemTestScripts\halosysNewScripts\localWorkspace\halosysus_halomem-newtests\conf_importapp.js:33:38)
>       at C:\Users\tanushree.y\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\util.js:48:49
>       at Function.promise (C:\Users\tanushree.y\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:682:9)
>       at Object.runFilenameOrFn_ (C:\Users\tanushree.y\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\util.js:38:16)
>       at C:\Users\tanushree.y\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:93:27
>       at _fulfilled (C:\Users\tanushree.y\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
>       at Promise.then.Q.nextTick.self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\tanushree.y\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\tanushree.y\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
>       at C:\Users\tanushree.y\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
>       at runSingle (C:\Users\tanushree.y\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
>   [11:42:23] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100

Comment: did you properly install the npm module using the command `npm install jasmine-reporters`?

Comment: put () like `new jasmineReporters().JUnitXmlReporter({........` not  `jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({........`

Comment: Could you share the complete stack trace of the error?

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj Yes I have installed the jasmine-reporters with  following command `npm install --save-dev jasmine-reporters@^2.0.0`

Comment: @Danny after trying `framework: 'jasmine2',
    onPrepare: function() {
        var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters().JUnitXmlReporter({
            consolidateAll: true,
            savePath: 'testresults',
            filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
        }));
    },`
I am getting this error

_E/launcher - Error: TypeError: jasmineReporters is not a function_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jasmine-reporters should be updated not only in our system but also in the project repository we have node-modules folder. there also we need to update the jasmine-reporters version.
This was the mistake I was doing I was updating jasmine in my system but it worked for me when I updated jasmine-reporters in node-modules in the project repository.
Its very silly thing to be missed out.